# Can peerJS make local stream without access internet

Tags: angular, webrtc, peerjs

I done setup peerJS server follow this url https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server.
Setup follow by nodeJs + express.

[image]

I also setup client peerJs using angular Apps. Everything is fine when I have connection with internet. But I getting error once internet close connection. I try to make my apps running in local network without access internet.

Below is my configuration if peerJs client.

[image]

I also import peerjs as local in angular apps.

[image]

Below error appear once start apps without internet connection.

[image]

Any one can advise for setup peerJs locally without access internet?

Comment: Did you already try to exchange some data between the peers after the error message? That is expected. The connection to the server is disconnected, but the WebRTC connection is still alive if your devices are in the same (Wi-Fi) network for example.

Comment: Not yet exchange some data between after error msg. I will try after this. I asking 1 question, can webrtc running local Network without access internet? I possible, with part I miss.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed the part that you start the app from beginning without an internet connection. My previous comment would only be true if the internet connection would drop later (after a connecton to the peer server was established and between another peer). I will post a real answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

PeerJS server acts as a WebRTC signaling server.

If you're running PeerJS server locally in your local (Wi-Fi) network and your peers (clients) are in the same network, you don't need an internet connection.

If your PeerJS server is available in a different network (via internet), you have these options for your clients:

1. establish an internet connection for a few seconds: connect to the PeerJS server, then connect to a peer. Now you can disconnect from the PeerJS server (and from the internet if the other client is still in the same local network)
2. if the other peer is in the same local network, you need to do the signaling yourself.

To do signaling yourself you can check this code: https://github.com/lesmana/webrtc-without-signaling-server

here is a demo/gif: https://mac-blog.org.ua/webrtc-one-to-one-without-signaling-server

In a real world there are some other obstacles like firewalls and NAT. To solve them you need a STUN or even a TURN (relay) server.